# Scrapy with deeper level using Xpath

Tags: xml, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrap information, the information I am looking for is accessible from a search adress:
[http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd+and+state%3DMN&first=2008&last=2011][1]

I want scrapy to follow the written link  (let's try for one then I will look for generating the number associated with)
the Xpath for one link is:

```
/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[29]/td[3]/a[2]
```

after crawling to this link I want scrappy to crawl to the xml files available on the next page. The Xpath for the link is general:

```
//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a
```

and finally I want scrapy to scrap some data from the xml page.

Launching Scrapy with: scrapy crawl DFORM -o items.json -t json
All I get on my json file is: "[".

***items.py***

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class SecformD(Item):
    company = Field()
    filling_date = Field()
    types_of_securities = Field()
    offering_amount = Field()
    sold_amount = Field()
    remaining = Field()
    investors_accredited = Field()
    investors_non_accredited = Field()
```

***Formds_Crawler.py***

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import BaseSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from formds.items import SecformD


class SecDform(CrawlSpider):
    name = "DFORM"
    allowed_domain = ["http://www.sec.gov"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd+and+state%3DMN&first=2008&last=2011"
        ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[27]/td[3]/a[2]')), callback='parse_formd', follow= True),)


def parse_formd(self, response):
    xxs = XMLPathSelector(response)
    hsx = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    sites = xxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = SecFormD()
        item['company'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible1"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['filling_date'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible40"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['types_of_securities'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible37"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['offering_amount'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible39"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['sold_amount'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible39"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['remaining'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible39"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['investors_accredited'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible40"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['investors_non_accredited'] = site.select('//*[@id="collapsible40"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()

        items.append(item)
    return items


***Here is the log:***
USComputer:formds psykoboy$ scrapy crawl DFORM -o items.json -t json
2013-07-18 21:18:37-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.4 started (bot: formds)
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [DFORM] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [DFORM] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-07-18 21:18:38-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-18 21:18:42-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=81&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:43-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd+and+state%3DMN&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:44-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=161&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:45-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=241&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:45-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=321&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:46-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=401&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:46-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=481&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:47-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=561&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:47-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=641&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:48-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=721&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:48-0500 [DFORM] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd%20and%20state%3DMN&start=721&count=80&first=2008&last=2011> (referer: None)
2013-07-18 21:18:48-0500 [DFORM] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-07-18 21:18:48-0500 [DFORM] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 3419,
     'downloader/request_count': 11,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 11,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 68182,
     'downloader/response_count': 11,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 11,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 19, 2, 18, 48, 189346),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 17,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'response_received_count': 11,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 11,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 11,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 11,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 11,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 19, 2, 18, 38, 701571)}
2013-07-18 21:18:48-0500 [DFORM] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: what does the log say? do you get some kind of Exception?

Comment: Well, you should have 3 steps here: 1. scrapy crawls the main page and  follows the link at 27-th row; 2. you should scrape the link to html and xml documents 3. scrape all the data from html and xml forms. Is it right?

Comment: Paul I attach the log, he don't say much about any error. Alecxe, it is right until the second step, I want only one link on the second page then 3 scrape the data from the xml page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **remove the `tbody/`** your first 2 XPath expressions work in `scrapy shell`

```
paul@wheezy:~$ scrapy shell 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=form-type%3Dd+and+state%3DMN&first=2008&last=2011'
...
In [1]: hxs.select('/html/body/div/table/tr[27]/td[3]/a[2]/@href').extract()
Out[1]: [u'/Archives/edgar/data/1490747/000149074710000001/0001490747-10-000001-index.htm']
In [2]: next = hxs.select('/html/body/div/table/tr[27]/td[3]/a[2]/@href').extract()[0]
In [3]: import urlparse
In [4]: next_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, next)
In [5]: next_url
Out[5]: u'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1490747/000149074710000001/0001490747-10-000001-index.htm'
In [6]: fetch(next_url)
2013-07-19 09:42:58+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1490747/000149074710000001/0001490747-10-000001-index.htm> (referer: None)
...
In [8]: hxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tr[3]/td[3]/a')
Out[8]: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tr[3]/td[3]/a' data=u'<a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1490747/00'>]
```

But the

```
sites = xxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a')
items = []
for site in sites:
    ... extract item values
```

part is not what you meant.

You want to follow the links to the XML documents, and parse them,
so you need to tell Scrapy to fetch those pages, `sites = xxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a')` does not do that, it returns the `a` tags, it does not issue a request to get the document

You would need something like:

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request
...
class SecDform(CrawlSpider):
    ...
    def parse_formd(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tr[3]/td[3]/a/@href').extract()
        for site in sites:
            yield Request(url=urlparse.urljoin(response.url, site), callback=self.parse_xml_document)
```

And define a new `parse_xml_document()` callback method that contains your Item extraction logic for these XML documents.

Your XPath expressions for your item fields come from Chrome or Firebug explorer, right? ("collapsibla0" etc.). What you need is work on the XML structure directly, not what the browser converts to HTML to display.
I only did the "company" part to illustrate.

```
    def parse_xml_document(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = SecFormD()
        item["company"] = xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/entityName/text()').extract()[0]
        ...
        return item
```

A good way to work on you XPath expression for your items it to use `scrapy shell <url_of_xml_document>` as I do below for "company" (see also http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#trying-selectors-in-the-shell)

```
paul@wheezy:~$ scrapy shell http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1490747/000149074710000001/primary_doc.xml
In [6]: xxs.select('./primaryIssuer')
Out[6]: [<XmlXPathSelector xpath='./primaryIssuer' data=u'<primaryIssuer>\n        <cik>0001490747<'>]

In [7]: xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/entityName')
Out[7]: [<XmlXPathSelector xpath='./primaryIssuer/entityName' data=u'<entityName>AEI CREDIT TENANT FUND 35 LP'>]

In [8]: xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/entityName/text()')
Out[8]: [<XmlXPathSelector xpath='./primaryIssuer/entityName/text()' data=u'AEI CREDIT TENANT FUND 35 LP'>]

In [9]: xxs.select('./primaryIssuer/entityName/text()').extract()
Out[9]: [u'AEI CREDIT TENANT FUND 35 LP']

In [10]:
```

---

Edit: updated gist with Rules() to follow [NEXT] pages and links to docs in all rows
https://gist.github.com/redapple/02a55aa6aaac0df2fb75

Comment: Thanks Paul, I do now understand how to find the right xpath (and yes I was using chrome inspection). I think I still have a problem with the rules: `    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/div/table/tr[27]/td[3]/a[2]/@href')), callback='parse_formd', follow= True),)` when i try to launch it seems to not find the link to follow. I try to make another function to repeat the process that you initiate without sucess.

Comment: restrict_xpaths should select elements, not element attributes, so remove the `/@href`

Comment: My bad: in `parse_formd()` on should use `HtmlXPathSelector` and call `.extract()` to get the `href` values for sites (and not the selectors). Also in `parse_xml_document`, xxs was wrong, now uses `XmlXPathSelector`

Comment: "working" code to be completed for other fields' XPath https://gist.github.com/redapple/02a55aa6aaac0df2fb75

Comment: Waw! thank you very much, I guess by this trial and error I learn a lot about Scrapy! I am now trying to make him crawl each link of the page `/html/body/div/table/tr[2]/td[**X**]/a[2]` and X will be a number ranging from 1 to 80, I though about a for loop but with the restrict_path I am not sure it is the way to go, if you have any recommandation to look? Thanks again for making this right!

Comment: If you want to loop on each row in the main table of your start_url, with XPath, it's even simpler than that: simply do not set an index for TR, so `/html/body/div/table/tr/td[3]/a[2]` in your Rule will make scrapy consider all `[html]` links and call `parse_formd()`. Then you'll want to follow `[NEXT]` pages

Comment: I updated the gist with one way to follow all links in table and next pages

Comment: So by deleting the index [] '/html/body/div/table/tr/td[3]/a[2]' scrapy will take all the different value, it is just amazing! and about the new rule with contains, so you told scrapy to allow him to follow every page that contains the word [NEXT] at that specific location: '/html/body/div/center[1]/a[contains(., "[NEXT]")]' what is the reason that we just don't do like for the TR? (I just tried and I get the same number of data). Merci Paul!

Comment: Indeed, `restrict_xpaths='/html/body/div/center[1]/a'` will get all links in the first <center>, and scrapy will fetch all the pages at once. Scrapy has a handy built-in duplicate request filter, so links called "2" and "[NEXT]" on the first page, which have the same `href` will be fetched only once. And on page 2, the Rule() will again match all links (pages already scraped, some pages already enqueued probably) so many requests will be filtered, thankfully. In the end, you'll get the same data, y method is simply a bit gentler on the server, 1 next parsing page at a time. Hope it's clearer.